# jQuery UI nestedSortable using connectWith and maxLevels not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

Since I'm using jQuery UI's sortable extension nestedSortable I'm trying to accomplish to create multiple (connected) lists with each having their seperate option in maximum nested levels.
But the plug-in checks for the amount of maximum levels in the original item (being dragged) instead of the place where it is supposed to be dropped.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_isAllowed: function(parentItem, levels) {
    var o = this.options;
    // Are we trying to nest under a no-nest or are we nesting too deep?
    if (parentItem == null || !(parentItem.hasClass(o.disableNesting))) {
        if (o.maxLevels < levels && o.maxLevels != 0) {
            this.placeholder.addClass(o.errorClass);
            this.beyondMaxLevels = levels - o.maxLevels;
        } else {
            this.placeholder.removeClass(o.errorClass);
            this.beyondMaxLevels = 0;
        }
    } else {
        this.placeholder.addClass(o.errorClass);
        if (o.maxLevels < levels && o.maxLevels != 0) {
            this.beyondMaxLevels = levels - o.maxLevels;
        } else {
            this.beyondMaxLevels = 1;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How am I able to make this part of the plug-in select the maxLevel option of the location where the item is being dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick (dirty) fix to solve to problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_isAllowed: function(parentItem, levels) {
    var o = this.options;
    o.maxLevels=$(this.placeholder[0]).closest('.ui-sortable').nestedSortable("option","maxLevels");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for noticing this problem. I've included your fix in the script, it will be pushed to github soon, probably today.

Comment: Could you update me as soon as there is a definitive fix? Thanks!

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it